# What does this iframe do?

Tags: html, iframe

```
<iframe id="esw_storage_iframe" src="https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.html?parent=https://firstfinancialstage-65.adobecqms.net/personal.html" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

From what I can tell it just references the home page

Edit:
The iframe is placed on the same page it references as the parent. The second link at the end of the iframe is the same page it is on. I'm confused as to why the iframe would reference the same page it is placed on.

Comment: An `<iframe>` is for embedding another webpage/url inside of another.  What are you asking?  Is there something special this url is doing that you are wondering about?  What do you mean by "it just references the home page"?

Comment: Also with `style="display: none;"`, you're not going to be seeing anything.

Comment: I'm familiar with the purpose of an iframe in general. I've just never seen this structure before. What would be the purpose of having a blank iframe that references the same page that it is placed on? I'm wondering if it has anything to do with session storage.

Comment: Could be for some sort of ad tracking or counting page views.  So this iframe is being used on the `firstfinancialstage-65.adobecqms.net` page?  The _real_ question here is then, what is `service.force.com`?  If that's some sort of tracker, then it needs to know what page it's tracking.

Comment: service.force has to do with Salesforce. There is a Salesforce chatbot on the page, but it is not inserted through an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Usually iframe in HTML is used to embed another document or webpage in the current HTML document. SO if we look at you code, we have id = esw_storage_iframe (maybe some element's id from website), the source website is just a blank page (i did check it), in the end we have `display: none;` : it makes it invisible.

Comment: I'm just wondering why would the iframe be blank and then parent a page that it is on. The parent link is the same page that the iframe is displayed on.